# Can I remove Zen Default Regions if Im not using them

Tags: theming

I want to remove regions such as 'navigation' & 'highlighted' from structure/blocks just so I can visually see what is in use, and not have a list of Blocks im not using sitting there.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove regions that have blocks in them - at least not without consequences. If you will do so, blocks will disappear and there is a chance for Drupal and PHP errors. To get rid of unneeded regions, you need to proceed in that order:

1. Remove all blocks from them
2. Remove them from `.tpl` files, to be sure nothing will try to render region that does not exist anymore
3. Now you can delete them from `.info` file

Answer (score 0):

You can remove entire regions by taking them out of your .info file for that theme. Your .info file will be located in the Zen theme folder and should be called zen.info. Open your .info file and remove the line that states:

regions[navigation]     = Navigation bar

If you want to keep things clean and orderly, you should also remove any call to those regions in any page.tpl.php files you have. They'll look something like:

```
<?php print $header ?>
```

And you may want to make a custom theme of your own if you plan on making a bunch of modifications.